# Connect iPhone with Facebook API

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I want to connect Facebook API's with my iPhone. For this I have downloaded the FBConnect SDK and included the FBConnect group of `FBConnect.xcodeproj` in my application and then I have written the following code in FacebookAPPViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     session = [FBSession sessionForApplication:@"a31c3e53bba4a5f2b3955d6e5e 876717" secret:@"6ecbefa3807406bd13187297e58efae9" delegate:self];
     FBLoginButton *button = [[[FBLoginButton alloc] init] autorelease];
     [self.view addSubview:button];

     FBLoginDialog* dialog = [[[FBLoginDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
     [dialog show];
}
```

but it is showing error that **session undeclared**. That is right also because I have not initialized it but if I declare it with class `FBSession` then also it displays some error and if I exclude this line then the button to connect to Facebook does not appear.

Can some one help me?

Answer (score 0):

After setting up the session, you should pass it to the login dialog:

```
FBSession *session = [FBSession 
             sessionForApplication:@"a31c3e53bba4a5f2b3955d6e5e 876717"
             secret:@"6ecbefa3807406bd13187297e58efae9" delegate:self];

FBLoginDialog* dialog = [[[FBLoginDialog alloc] initWithSession:session] autorelease];

[dialog show];
```

In your example, you're opening the login dialog right away, so there's no need to add a login button to your view.

PS. I hope you didn't use your real secret key in your code sample...